# How to control the dropdown menu icon with collapse / expand in angular?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, icons, dropdown

I tried to customize the dropdown menu in navigation bar. I would like to control the icon when user click/close the dropdown menu.

-fa-angle-up when the user open the dropdown

-fa-angle-down when the user close/default the dropdown

What is the problem on it ?

[here is stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-477zjb?file=src/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your sample. See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9b6nep?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Remove bracket in `[ngClass]`.

```
[ngClass]="menuExpandCategory ? 'fa-angle-up' : 'fa-angle-down'"
```

And it looks you also have to move your toggle function into `<a>` tag.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a
    (click)="menuExpandCategory = !menuExpandCategory"
    class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                 :
  >
```

Comment: thanks for help. However, I found the bug that click dropdown menu and then click outside will trigger problem.